# How to rework this sequential network program for better performance?

Tags: c, ruby, concurrency, web

I've written a little Ruby script that takes a file of URLs, checks for the existence of a link to a website (specified as a command line parameter) on the webpage of that URL and, if the link is not marked 'nofollow', it prints the URL to STDOUT. The purpose of the program is to filter out websites that link to the specified website but do not pass link juice.

It works okay, however, the script takes hours to check ~3000 webpages. I would like to improve this, mostly for fun and to learn some techniques for solving this type of problem in the future. My primary goal is to rewrite the program in such a way that it's able to saturate the network connection because network I/O is the current bottleneck.

Now, I have no idea what the best way to tackle this would be. I understand structuring a program in an event-driven manner is often used to write efficient network code and that the alternative seems to be using threads. It's my (incorrect?) understanding, though, that Ruby doesn't really support concurrent programming because the Ruby runtime uses a global lock.

I currently know C, also, but, if there's some other language that's particularly suited to this kind of thing (especially on a large scale, think millions of URLs instead of thousands), I can dedicate some time to learning that language because I plan on building some similar programs in the future. Right tool for the job and all that.

So, my questions are, roughly:

- Is Ruby or C a suitable candidate for solving this problem in an efficient manner?
- How would I structure such a program? What libraries should I use?

If neither Ruby nor C are suitable:

- What language would be a good fit for this type of program?
- How would I structure such a program? What libraries should I use?

Here's what my script looks like right now:

```
(argument parsing code omitted)

def dofollow?(link)
  if not link.attr("rel").nil?
    if link.attr("rel").include?("nofollow")
      return false
    end
  end
  return true
end

options = parse(ARGV)

File.open(options.file, "r") do |file|
 file.each do |website|
    begin
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(website))
      doc.css("a").each do |link|
        if link.attr("href").include?(options.url) && dofollow?(link)
          puts website
          break
        end
      end
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Even though Ruby does use GIL I'm pretty sure that using a new thread for `file.each` will improve performances since each thread does not need to access any global variables. It only processes the variable it is given when initialized and outputs to STDOUT. I wrote a mini-stress test for a website and used threads and it worked fine.

Comment: Funnily enough, using `sh` (`bash`, `zsh`, or whatever) may be an option. `sh` uses a multiprocess paradigm, you would just need to background the fragment that deals with each website to achieve good concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a parallel http library like [Typhoeus](http://rubygems.org/gems/typhoeus). It's a ruby API but it uses the C bindings to libcurl for fast parallel fetching.

Another excellent library is [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request), which runs on the eventmachine event framework for parallel requests.